# Form alter in a specific content type

Tags: 7, forms

how can i alter/inject a form in a specific content type. I'm developing a module (product list/shopping cart) to insert a form after the body of a specific content type but right now it's showing up in all the existing content types.

The module was not initially developed by me so i'm having a bit of trouble picking up from where it was left…

Here is the part i think is relevant:

```
function ftf_product_form_node_form_alter(&$form, $form_state) {


  $products = db_select('ftf_product')->fields(NULL, array('pid', 'nid', 'name', 'font_ref', 'description', 'app', 'web', 'desktop',  'avangate_desktop', 'avangate_web', 'avangate_app'))->condition('nid', $form['nid']['#value'], '=');
  $result = $products->execute();
  foreach ($result as $record) {
    $defaults[] = $record;
  }

  if(empty($form_state['num_products'])) {
    $results = $products->countQuery()->execute()->fetchField();
    $form_state['num_products'] = $results;

    if($form_state['num_products']  == 0) {
      $form_state['num_products'] = 1;
    }
  }

  $form['products'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('<strong>Typeface products</strong>'),
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
    '#collapsed' => (($defaults[$form_state['num_products']-1]->name && !$_SESSION["collapse_typeface_product"])?TRUE:FALSE), 
    '#weight' => 5,
    '#tree' => TRUE,
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('container-inline')),
    '#prefix' => '<div id="participants"><p>&nbsp;</p>',
    '#suffix' => '</div><p>&nbsp;</p>',
    '#description' => t('<p style="color:grey">Create, edit and delete products here. To add or edit Typeface Price Factors please visit the <a href="/admin/config/content/ftf_pricetable">admin section</a>.</br></br></p>'), 
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function ftf_product_form_node_form_alter(&$form, $form_state) {

  if($form['#node']->type == 'YOUR_NODE_TYPE'){
    $products = db_select('ftf_product')->fields(NULL, array('pid', 'nid', 'name', 'font_ref', 'description', 'app', 'web', 'desktop',  'avangate_desktop', 'avangate_web', 'avangate_app'))->condition('nid', $form['nid']['#value'], '=');
    $result = $products->execute();
    foreach ($result as $record) {
      $defaults[] = $record;
    }

    if(empty($form_state['num_products'])) {
      $results = $products->countQuery()->execute()->fetchField();
      $form_state['num_products'] = $results;

      if($form_state['num_products']  == 0) {
        $form_state['num_products'] = 1;
      }
    }

    $form['products'] = array(
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => t('<strong>Typeface products</strong>'),
      '#collapsible' => TRUE,
      '#collapsed' => (($defaults[$form_state['num_products']-1]->name && !$_SESSION["collapse_typeface_product"])?TRUE:FALSE), 
      '#weight' => 5,
      '#tree' => TRUE,
      '#attributes' => array('class' => array('container-inline')),
      '#prefix' => '<div id="participants"><p>&nbsp;</p>',
      '#suffix' => '</div><p>&nbsp;</p>',
      '#description' => t('<p style="color:grey">Create, edit and delete products here. To add or edit Typeface Price Factors please visit the <a href="/admin/config/content/ftf_pricetable">admin section</a>.</br></br></p>'), 
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to alter only one specific form, [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) is ideal. Replace `FORM_ID` with the `form_id` of your content type (should be something like `machine_name_node_form` - `print $form_id`). That hook's implementation has the advantage of not being invoked by all forms, but only by the specified form. This is important in terms of performance.

Hope it helps!